# Does not work <!--more--> in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying use the `<!--more-->` in WP, but its does not work. I'm using 
Wordpress 3.6.1. What is the problem?

Text in redactor of post:

```
     Abc<!--more-->cba
```

How I use:

```
<?php
$args = array( 'posts_per_page' => 10, 'order'=> 'ASC', 'orderby' => 'title' );  
$postslist = get_posts( $args );  
foreach ($postslist as $post) :  setup_postdata($post); ?>  
    <div>  
    <?php the_date(); ?>  
    <br />  
    <?php the_title(); ?>  
    <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
    <?php the_content(); ?>  
    </div>  
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Try moving it after `cba` or putting a space between them. I wonder if it's a placement issue.

Comment: Do you have `global $post;` declared somewhere before this code? setup_postdata() needs the $post you pass it to be the global one in order for other functions to work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

i havent used redactor plugin (is the redactor plugin what you are talking about?).

just tested, if you add `<!--more-->` into editor, then wp 3.6.1 definitely removes comments and replaces it with `<span>` tag, but only does this when post is viewed from frontend, so it is still saved in db as `<!--more-->`, interesting.

on wp 3.5.2 this didn't happen for me. by the way i'm not using redactor when i tried this test.

is this what you mean

Comment: hm, I am not useing html redactor in WP, I am useing text redactor in WP. What should I do?

Comment: give me a link to `text redactor`, i cant find any info on it. maybe try a different wp version, rather than using 3.6.1. many plugins have not been tested for the latest wp version